# Arrow is too long when \vec followed by subscript or superscript after using unicode-math package

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode-math

The code is below

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}    
\setmathfont{XITS Math}    
\begin{document}    
\large    
$\vec{a}^{12345}$    
\end{document}
```

Then the arrow of `\vec` is too long and penetrate the superscript 12.
I just want the the arrow of `\vec` is above `a`, not whole of `a^{12345}`
And I use `xelatex` to run the code.

However, if I replace `$\vec{a}^{12345}$` with `$\vec{ab}^{12345}$`, then it looks quite good. The arrow of `\vec` is just above `ab`, it do not stretch and penetrate 12.

Can anyone tell me how to fix the problem?

Comment: Just mentioning that compiling with `lualatex` gives the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

This is a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3067487&group_id=194926&atid=951385) in XeTeX's math accent handling, should be fixed in the coming TeX Live 2012.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like single-character arguments to `\vec` are handled differently. In that sense, supplying a fake two-element argument solves your problem:

```
$\vec{a{}}^{12345}
```