# Argument of … has an extra }, recursive macro

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, recursion

Note: This is (unfortunately) not a simple “fix your matching braces” issue, please read the whole question.

I’m working on a command to fix the spacing of `\vec` — the spacing is too small by default, leading to collisions with the arrow and following glyphs in cases like `(\vec p)`. However, simply redefining the command, as in

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldvec\vec
\def\vec#1{\oldvec{#1}\@ifnextchar{^}{\kern 1pt}{}}
\makeatother
```

doesn’t work in cases where the vector has both a superscript *and* a subscript. Therefore, a command that recursively deals with oncoming super- and subscripts is required.

Currently, I’m using the following solution (optimized for Stix/Times, so may not look great with Computer Modern). However, a subscript containing a single command that takes an argument will fail unless the atom is encased in braces (e.g. `\vec a_\textup{max}` doesn’t work, `\vec a_{\textup{max}}` and `\vec a_\pi` work).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\oldvec\vec
\def\vec#1{\oldvec{#1}\vec@}
\def\vec@{%
    \@ifnextchar{_}{\vec@sub}{%
    \@ifnextchar{^}{\vec@sup}{{\kern 0.5pt}}}%
}%
\def\vec@sub#1#2{_{\kern -0.75pt #2}\vec@}
\def\vec@sup#1#2{^{\kern 2pt #2}\vec@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% works
\[ \vec s_{\textrm{max}} \]

% doesn't work
\[ \vec s_\textrm{max} \]
\end{document}
```

Error code:

```
! Argument of \textrm  has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.16 \[ \vec s_\textrm
                      {max} \]
```

I think it has to do with the `\vec@sub` and `\vec@sup` commands ending a group before the argument is given (so that the parser sees `{\vec{a}_\textrm}{a}` or something and panics) but I’m not entirely sure how to figure that out.

Full disclosure: This code is “adapted” (read: nearly entirely copied from) [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334190/94878) by @siracusa, and it definitely involves TeX code a little bit higher than my normal skill level. I have read what I could find on `\@ifnextchar` and so on, but I’m not 100% certain on all the elements playing out here.

Thanks for your help with this oddball problem!

Comment: Off topic: Why not use `\max`?

Comment: Both `\[ \vec s_\max \]` and `\[ \vec s_{\textrm{max}} \]` do not produce errors here. But the second has bigger `max` font.

Comment: @Sigur The short answer is that the text isn’t always `max`. Things like `offset`, `thrust`, etc.

Comment: `_{<arg>}` is the correct syntax anyway.

Comment: Why do you use `\textrm` in math mode? Why not `\mathrm`?

Comment: the fact that `_\textrm{a}` works using a primitive subscript is an unfortunate side effect of the primitive behaviour. It is very hard to support that using macro arguments and is anyway incorrect latex syntax so it is better just do document that it is not supported as do other packages that use macros here eg breqn or tex4ht etc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So just to clarify, the answer here is “don’t do that”? As in, the support of something like `a_\textrm{bbb}` is purely accidental? If that’s true, I suppose I’m OK with not supporting that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Martin At this point I’ve switched to `\text{...}` but that’s irrelevant; this question is general to any command that takes an argument.

Comment: @9999years it's not entirely accidental that it works with the primitive _ but it has never been supported latex syntax. the latex book will tell you even to brace a single character `x^{2}` not `x^2` but certainly if `_` is a macro `_\textrm{zz}`  is the same as `_{\textrm}{zz}`  and gives an error just as `\fbox\textrm{zz}` is `\fbox{\textrm}{zz}` and gives the same error.

Comment: possibly helpful: [Arrow is too long when \vec followed by subscript or superscript after using unicode-math package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51148/579)

Answer (score 4):

The fact that `_\textrm{a}` works using a primitive subscript is an unfortunate side effect of the primitive behaviour. It is very hard to support that using macro arguments and is anyway incorrect latex syntax so it is better just do document that it is not supported as do other packages that use macros here eg breqn or tex4ht etc.

The fact that it works depends on `_` being a tex primitive not a macro, and on the internal details of `\textrm` and similar commands (that expand to a single brace group).  The outwardly similar construct `x_\fbox{a}` does not work for example and requires `x_{\fbox{a}}`.

If `_` is made into a macro then it (most likely) loses this ability to find braces hidden inside macros. If instead of `_` you use `\fbox\textrm{x}` then you get essentially the same error as you shown because `\fbox` gets *just* `\textrm` as argument. The correct markup is `\fbox{\textrm{a}}`